# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE received for one specific configuration page. Caching Problem?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, apache2

**Background:** 
As of today, I backed up my database, and was testing an unleashed integration with my magento installation. Randomly, I noticed that I was having the same JS errors across my entire admin. I ignored them as they weren't causing problems in my LOCAL environment.

After doing this and also working on the OneStepCheckout plugin from Idev, I realized that I could not get to my payment options config section to turn on paypal sandbox, and I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE or occasionally an ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNK_RESPONSE  from chrome whenever I try to load the page. It seems like sometimes it can load the page almost of all of the way, but sometimes it does not.

So, at this point, I've started to pare down the JS errors, to see if they are causing these problems. This has had no effect.

I have considered a JS conflict between jQuery & Prototype, but I'm not using any jQuery in the admin area, only on the frontend, so I think its unlikely.

I've also increased php memory_limit and max_post_size, didn't help, as far as I can tell.

I have also noticed posts about xcache and caching corruption, and I've investigated, but not that thoroughly, as I'm not expert on caching. I don't think my development box has xcache or any special caching on it, though.

Also thought it might have something do with unleashed, but a backup of the database uploaded over the database version unleashed was connected to had no effect.

**My real question:** 
Apart from all that, is there any other reason why I would be getting these type of errors suddenly, and only having them affect the system on a live server, rather than my local dev environment??

Any help would be great. Banging my head against the wall at this point.